# Proof that if $v_1,. . .v_n$ spans $V$, then $v_1 -v_2,. . .,v_{n-1} - v_n, v_n$ also spans $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I saw the following problem in Linear Algebra Done Right and thought if the general version of it would hold.

Problem: Suppose that $v_1,.  .  .,v_4$. spans $V$. Prove that $v_1 - v_2,v_2-v_3,v_3-v_4,v_4$ also spans $V$.

I would like if someone could confirm if the following proof is correct.

Q: Suppose that $v_1,.  .  .,v_n$ spans $V$. Prove that $v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,.  .  .,v_{n-1}-v_n,v_n$ also spans $V$ for $n\geq 2$.

Proof: It suffices to show that there exists scalars such that $a_1(v_1-v_2)+.  .  .+a_{n-1}(v_{n-1}-v_n)+a_nv_n = c_1v_1+.  .  .+c_nv_n$.

Let

$a_1 = c_1$

$a_2 =c_1+c_2$

.
.
.

$a_{n-1}=c_1+.  .  .+c_{n-1}$

$a_n=c_1+. . .+c_n$

Then, $a_1(v_1-v_2)+.  .  .+a_{n-1}(v_{n-1}-v_n)+a_nv_n=c_1v_1+.  .  .+c_nv_n$.

Proving the desired result.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: How are you quantifying $a_i$'s and $c_i$'s? As stated your proof is incomplete at best, incorrect at worst. A much simpler solution is to show that $v_{n-1}\in W:=\text{span}\{v_1-v_2,\dots, v_{n-1}-v_n,v_n\}$. Then, show $v_{n-2}\in W$, then show $v_{n-3}\in W$ and so on (a rigorous proof uses induction). Why does this complete the proof?

Comment: @peek-a-boo If we let $F$ denote the field or real or complex numbers. Then there exists scalars $a_1,. . .,a_n \in F$ such that for any $c_1,. . .,c_n \in F$, the claim holds.

Comment: Nope, still incorrect.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh I think I got what you mean. I’ll give that a try.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the answer somewhat. For clarity you may want to add a sentence like *Let $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n$ be arbitrary scalars* and then continuing with the explanation *It suffices to show that there exist coefficients $a_i$ such that
$$a_1(v_1-v_2)+\cdots+a_{n-1}(v_{n-1}-v_n)+a_nv_n=\sum_i c_iv_i.$$* In other words, the logic stands out loud and clear only when you explain which coefficients are given, and which are the ones you play with. Your approach is, in the end, sound (because you are essentially solving for the $a_i$s), but at least for me this was warning sign :-) +1

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Could somebody explain why do you give answers in comments, not in 'Your Answer' section. The placeholder in the comment section says: 'Avoid answering questions in comments'. I'm quite new on this forum and I don't understand this phenomenon.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Could somebody explain why do you give answers in comments, not in 'Your Answer' section. The placeholder in the comment section says: 'Avoid answering questions in comments'. I'm quite new on this forum and I don't understand this phenomenon.

Comment: @Mateo OP is essentially asking a 'check my work' question, and in my experience these are better discussed in comments. Even if I write up my comments as an answer, OP would still end up asking the same follow-up questions for clarification, so I don't see any benefit to me prematurely writing up an answer.

Comment: @Mateo Others have wondered about the same thing. I have many reasons, none really compelling. 1) I somehow doubt the wisdom of having many solution-verifications for they typically serve one person only. 2) This is in the class of questions, where I instinctively want to induce the asker to see the light themself. 3) The question is very standard (may be even an exact duplicate), and I loathe duplication of math content on this site. 4) When I write an answer to such question I strongly prefer it to contain some essential extras.

Comment: (cont'd) 5) I have a lot of rep already, and should not be eager to post answers to questions that are (for me) *turkey shoot*. The question is fine for students at that level, but I usually answer only, if other answers make a muck of it or leave something essential out. All these are my personal feelings about how the site should be used - not official policies.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let me denote the span of a set $S$ by $L(S)$ . So let us denote the set $\{v_{1}-v_{2},...,v_{n-1}-v_{n},v_{n}\}=T$ and $S=\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$

Two equivalent definitons of span:-

**1:-** The span of a set $S$ is the set of all finite linear combinations of the elements of $S$ .

**2:-** The span of a set $S$ is the smallest subspace $L(S)$ of $V$ such that $S\subseteq L(S)$ . By smallest we mean the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $S$.

Now notice that $(v_{n-1}-v_{n})+(v_{n})=v_{n-1}\in L(T)$

Then again $v_{n-2}-v_{n-1}+v_{n-1}=v_{n-2}\in L(T)$ .

Use a simple induction to prove that $\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}\in L(T)$

This directly gives you that $L(\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\})\subseteq L(L(T))=L(T)$

Also $T\subset L(S)\implies L(T)\subseteq L(L(S))=L(S)$

Thus $L(T)=L(S)$ .

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to tackle the problem. Notice that there is an $nxn$ matrix $A$ which is [image]

which satisfies
[image]

It is easy to notice that $A$ is invertible and therefore any

linear combination of the one side can be written as a linear

combination of the other side and vice versa. That is if a vector is a linear combination of v's is

[image]

which is a linear combination of $v_{i-1}-v_{i}$'s and we can do the same the inverse way, and that proves the result!

Comment: It isn't mentioned that $V$ is $n$-dimensional. Also, why bother showing independence (which here is the incorrect way to go anyway) when proving spanning is much simpler?

Comment: You are right, I did not notice that the given vectors were not necessarily independent. I will make a correction!